# return count of specific row in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, count

i have this table :

```
------------------------------
|PRODUCT_NAME | PRODUCT_COLOR|
------------------------------
|Name 1       | Red          |
|Name 1       | Green        |
|Name 1       | White        |
|Name 2       | Red          |
|Name 2       | Green        |
------------------------------
```

i need an SQL Query To Give me result like this :

```
------------------------------
|PRODUCT_NAME | PRODUCT_COLOR|
------------------------------
|Name 1       | 3            |
|Name 2       | 2            |
------------------------------
```

so it is counting how many color

is it possible ?

Comment: What is your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: PRODUCT_ID is the PRIMARY KEY

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Did you tried anything, what is your specific issue, which stops you from doing it?

Comment: Just check for `COUNT` and `GROUP BY` sql functions

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like simple aggregation:

```
select product_name, count(*) no_colors
from mytable
group by product_name
```

Or, if you have duplicates, and you want to count each color only once per products, then use `count(distinct ...)`:

```
select product_name, count(distinct product_color) no_colors
from mytable
group by product_name
```